# Email alias in Mail?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have an email account with a less than professional name that has lots of accounts linked to it, as well as my Google Play account etc. My school email and my more professional sounding Gmail account link to it instead, so emails that come in to those address go to my first account's inbox.

When I reply to these emails I want them to come from the emails they were actually sent to, not my first email. But it's also important to me to be able to read them from my primary email because there are so many things that go there, either from other email accounts that forward to it or just accounts that use that email.

Can I set this up in Pantheon mail?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, Mail supports aliases. Click the gear in the upper-right corner. `Accounts > select account > "Additional email addresses..." > add alias`. When you go to send or reply to an email, if you pop the email out into its own window, you can select the alias you would like to use.

Note that they will list in the format of "`alias@email.com via actual.account@email.com`" (indicating that they will be sent "on behalf of" the account if you don't add the alias as to Mail separately as full accounts.